# Fix a view for all screens by using container view

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview

I'm trying to build a music player. On bottom of all screens, there will be a music player controllers like play, pause etc.. and this view should be fixed. On other view, there will be icons and one icon is clicked, table view screen will be opened with .As I searched container view can solve this problem but I'm not sure If it is the proper way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in two ways:
Create a reusable component for Music controls. On first screen, use a collection view for showing icons. In footer of collection view use Music control reusable component.
    1. On click of an icon cell in collection view, push another view controller with a tableview. In footer of tableview use Music control reusable component.
    Or
    2. On click of icon cell in collection view, add another view controller with table view as child view controller and set it's bounds equal to that of collection view's bounds of parent view controller.

```
[self addChildViewController:secondVC];
CGRect frame = self.collectionview.bounds;
[secondVC.view setFrame:frame];
[self.view addSubview: secondVC.view];
[secondVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```